# How to check Page is Post back or not in SPD 2013? Using Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to check page is post back or not in SPD 2013. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
function isPostBack() {
    alert('Page is PostBack');
    }
```

Once the page is postback then this function will trigger, am not sure it will work or not but as earlier i have done something like this.

Comment: This is not work.